# MYSQL Prepared Statements Select Row_Count

Tags: mysql, select, prepared-statement

I have a simple SQL Query:

```
$stmt = $db_main->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username=? AND mail=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $mail);
$stmt->execute();
```

And I want to know, if it found an user. So I want to count the rows found. 
I already tried to use rowCount (Not safe for SELECT) or num_rows or just looking if the result id is numeric (Which '' would not be, I hoped...)

There has to be an easy way to count the selected row, hasn't be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check number of rows returned with:

```
$stmt->num_rows;
```

Check for instance [this site](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php).

***p.s.***: added as per question in comment: use `fetch()` in order to get the next record.

```
...
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($user_id); // access id
$stmt->store_result();        // optional: buffering (see below)

if ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
    do {
        print("Id: " . $user_id); 

    } while ($data = $stmt->fetch());

} else {
    echo 'No records found.';
}
```

Regarding `store_result()` from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php): 
*"You must call mysqli_stmt_store_result() for every query ..., if and only if you want to buffer the complete result set by the client ..."*

Comment: Well thanks for your fast answer, but I still don't get it :/

What I have now:

    
 $stmt = $db_main->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username=? AND mail=? LIMIT 1");
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $mail);
 $stmt->execute();  
 print("num:" . $stmt->num_rows);
 $stmt->close();

And the num_rows is working but how do I get the id now?

Comment: With your code I get: "Cannot access empty property" for the line:

    print("Id: " . $stmt->$data['id']); 

If i print_r($data) I just get '1'

Comment: A typo: it should be `$data['id']` ... alternatively you can use: `$stmt->bind_result($id);` ... `print("Id: " . $id);`

Comment: No way, it works!

If someone is interested in the result:
   
    $stmt = $db_main->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username=? AND mail=? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $mail);
    $stmt->execute();  
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id);
    $stmt->fetch();
    print("ID:" . $user_id . ", num_rows:" . $stmt->num_rows);
    $stmt->close();

Don't know why i didn't work before... Thank you!! 

If you give me 1 up, I can give you too :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'll update my answer above so that others might get a better understanding.